# Is there an intrinsic or natural topology on a field, motivating the definition of the Zariski topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, zariski-topology

Let $k$ be a field. The usual motivation for the Zariski topology on affine space $\mathbb{A}^n(k)$ is that it is the coarsest topology for which the algebraic sets, the zero loci of polynomials, are closed.

This can be phrased in more topological or categorical terms: we may characterize the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{A}^n$ as the initial topology with respect to all regular maps into $k$, if we endow $k$ with the topology where the only nontrivial closed set is $0$. Call this topology $\tau,$ so $\tau =\{\varnothing,k^\times,k\}.$

There are other topologies $k$ could carry for which the Zariski topology is the initial topology for regular maps in to $k$, including for example the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{A}^1\cong k.$ But for the purposes of parsimony, and for non-circularity in motivating the definition of the Zariski topology, I prefer to use $\tau$, which is the coarsest topology on $k$ with this property.

Does this topological space $(k,\tau)$ occur in the literature, or have a name? Is there a natural or intrinsic algebraic justification for this topology (whatever that might mean)? It seems like an algebraic analogue of [Sierpiński space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space), in that it classifies open sets in the regular category.

The only intrinsic topology that I know for an arbitrary ring is the $I$-adic topology. But the only ideal of a field is the zero ideal, and the $I$-adic topology for the zero ideal gives the discrete topology. So $\tau$ is not the $I$-adic topology.

I do not see any way to view $\tau$ as the Zariski topology on $k$, which, if it existed, should be the zero loci of the constant polynomials, hence the trivial topology. Actually that's not correct, that's not the Zariski topology on $k$, the Zariski topology is properly assigned to $\mathbb{A}^0=\text{pt}$, not to $k$, which is instead its coordinate ring. Anyway, $\tau$ is not the trivial topology.

We might identify $k$ with $\mathbb{A}^1,$ but the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{A}^1$ is usually the cofinite topology, which has $\lvert k\rvert$ many closed points, whereas $(k,\tau)$ has only one. So $\tau$ is not the Zariski topology either.

I'm hoping to provide an intrinsic motivation for this topology $\tau$ on $k$, to use in turn to motivate the definition of the Zariski topology from earlier principles, so even if we could view it as the Zariski (which, again, I don't see how we can), I'm hoping to hear a different justification.

Comment: thanks to @Pierre-GuyPlamondon for your comments, they were very helpful to clarify my question.

Comment: The answer here by Slade seemed relevant https://math.stackexchange.com/a/863562/16490

Comment: I think [this answer by Vladimir Sotirov](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/166211/16490) may contain hints of the answer

Comment: The closed sets of $\tau$ are  $\varnothing,\{0\},$ and $k$. Which are also the zero loci of the constant functions $k\to k$ plus the identity map. I wonder whether this leads to an answer

Comment: If instead of just declaring our field to carry a topology, we also demand it to be a topological monoid/ring, then in fact it may have more closed sets. If $\{0\}$ is closed, then every singleton should be closed, since addition is continuous. Therefore instead of $\tau=\{\emptyset,k^\times,k\}$, we actually do have the cofinite topology.

Answer (score 2):

Another way could be to endow $k$ with the trivial valuation. Let $v:k\to \{0\}\cup\{\infty\}$ be the trivial valuation. The open unit ball is the elements with valuation bigger than $0$, which is just $0$ in this case. So $k^\times$ is a closed set. And clearly $k$ is also a closed set. And there are no other closed sets.

Comment: I like this answer, because the spectrum of a DVR is literally Sierpinski space. But I'm confused. The spectrum of a field is a point, not Sierpinski space. I guess the usual definition of DVR does not allow the valuation to be trivial...?

Comment: Yes. Discrete valuation means the value group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. Which we are violating in this case.

Comment: @ziggurism In the $\mathbb Z$-valuation on a DVR, the units have valuation $0$, and the non-units have positive valuation. Similarly here, the units have valuation $0$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein so the assumption that your valuation is nontrivial means necessarily assuming our ring is not a field. I got it.

Comment: @ziggurism not quite...

Comment: @DustanLevenstein hmm let me try again. In a DVR the valuation must be surjective onto $\mathbb{Z}$, there are required to be some non-units of every positive valuation, while for our field $k$, our trivial valuation $\nu$ has no elements with $0<\nu(a)<\infty$? We only have non-units of valuation $\infty$?

Comment: And what's the maximal ideal in a DVR? Is it $\nu^{-1}(\mathbb{Z}\setminus 0),$ which is empty here?

Comment: @ziggurism Sorry didn't have the time to write an answer earlier. The valuation on a DVR extends to the field of fractions on a canonical way: The elements of $\mathfrak m^n$ which are not in $\mathfrak m^{n+1}$ have valuation $n$, for any $n \in \mathbb Z$ (where $\mathfrak m^n$ refers to the group operation on fractional ideals). A $\mathbb Z$-valuation on a field $k$ is precisely the same thing as a choice of DVR $D$ with $\operatorname{Frac}(D)=k$. This answer makes reference to the trivial valuation on $k$; there may be other valuations.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein ok I think I've got it now. $\mathfrak{m}=\nu^{-1}(n\geq1)=\bigcup_k^\infty \mathfrak{m}^k.$ Spec of a DVR has two points, the zero ideal $\nu^{-1}(\infty)$ and the maximal ideal. But our trivial valuation has only the zero ideal.

Comment: @ziggurism Correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think the usual way to describe this is that the inclusion $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{ 0 \} \to \mathbb{A}^1$ is the *universal standard open set*.

It's universal in the following sense: the standard open subsets of any affine scheme $X$ are in bijective correspondence with the inverse images of $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{0 \}$ under regular maps $X \to \mathbb{A}^1$.

Usually we write $D(f)$ for the standard open corresponding to $f : X \to \mathbb{A}^1$.

---

Incidentally, I don't think the phrase "universal standard open set" has common usage; it's just the natural description to give to the construction so described.

Comment: Perhaps this would be a good way to say it?Just as Sierpinski space $\top\to 2$ is the open subset classifier in Top, $\mathbb{A}^1\setminus 0\to\mathbb{A}^1$ is in Scm/$k$.

Comment: @ziggurism: It's not quite the *classifier* since there are open sets that aren't standard opens. For example, the open set $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{ (0,0) \}$ is not a standard open. (also, the classifying map wouldn't be unique; e.g. $D(f) = D(uf)$ for any unit $u$)

Comment: Hmm I see. To use that universal/univalent nomenclature, it's neither universal (exist exactly one), nor versal (exist one, not unique), nor univalent (exists at most one). It's the valent open set.

Comment: I think this answer was authored by Hurkyl, who has quit the site and deleted their account.